# Constrain a property value using Cypher constraints

Tags: neo4j, cypher, constraints

I am adding constraints to a neo4j database using Cypher contraints and have a property field on a node where I want the value to be one of a set of strings.

I have created a constraint that this field must exist but am unsure if you can constrain the value itself.

For example, my node may look like

`(e:Entity { foo: 'a' })`

and I have the constraint

`CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (e:Entity) ASSERT EXISTS (e.foo)`

but I only want `foo` to be either `a`, `b`, `c` or `d`, so in this example, the node would be fine. However, if I were to add another node

`(e:Entity { foo: 'e' })`,

then I would want this to fail and throw an exception.

The neo4j [Constraints documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/constraints/) suggests that there isn't currently a way of doing this. Has anybody come across this before and have a potential solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there's no way to configure a Neo4j constraint on property values. I've always implemented these types of constraints in the API layer. The allowed values can be defined in an Enum in whatever language you're using. Or they can be placed in Neo4j itself and cached in the API layer. Neither approach is perfect. The Enum approach requires a code change and deployment whenever the values change but invalid values are caught at compile time. Storing the values in Neo4j requires a cache refresh and invalid values are runtime errors.

Comment: @hoyski Thanks for the response. That's basically the conclusion I came to as well. I've already built typing in the API layer for CRUD operations. The reason I want to constrain the db as well is to mitigate issues coming from database migrations and batch uploads from other sources